# Access Flutter SharedPreferences in Swift

Tags: swift, flutter, sharedpreferences, userdefaults

Is it possible to access `SharedPreferences` saved from Flutter accessed in Swift code of plugin? In Android we have `FILE` mode for `SharedPreferences`.
Any similar feature in Swift 4?

Answer (score 16):

The [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) uses `NSUserDefaults` on iOS to store the data. You can easily access it with Swift like this:

```swift
let name = NSUserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "flutter.test")
print(name)
```

It would also make sense to use the *optional binding* to get the value safely:

```swift
if let name = NSUserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "flutter.test") {
    print(name)
}
```

Note, that if you use the key `test` in your flutter/dart code you would need to add the `flutter.` prefix to the key, as the [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin prefixes every key with it (see [this line](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/a3f9ce7f3d8437d314001d77f9b8e797fcbfea78/packages/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart#L20) in the source code)

Answer (score 4):

Use UserDefaults on Swift.

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"flutter.key"))
```

key = key used em flutter to shared preferences.
You need to use flutter prefix on key.

Comment: Straight to the point , as accepted answer is more likely depreciated

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure there exist anything like that, but you don't even need that.

You can fetch the value in Flutter itself, and then send the value using [MethodChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html).

Comment: There are cases when you want to reach prefs from within Swift.