# How to get shared_preferences in Share Extension

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, swift5, share-extension

I want to know how to get shared_preferences in iOS share extension (swift code).

I use 'shared_preferences' to store session date in this code.

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().setString("session", "session_sata")
```

And, I tried to get 'SharedPreferences' iOS in share extension (swift) by using `UserDefaults` like this code .

```
UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: "") 
UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "")
```

However, I couldn't get session date in swift code, even more I couldn't find a key of "flutter.session".

Does anyone know how to get shared_preferences in iOS share extension?

Reference
[Access Flutter SharedPreferences in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608338/access-flutter-sharedpreferences-in-swift)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to share data between an iOS host app and its app extension you need to:

1. Add the `App Group` capability/entitlement to the app and the extension
2. Set up an instance of UserDefaults initialized from a `suiteName`: `UserDefaults(suiteName: ${appGroupIdentifier})`

And unfortunately this is not possible with the current state of the [SharedPreferences pub](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64739) addressing this.

A possible solution to your problem is to try out this pub, which appears to be created to handle this use case: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preference_app_group